# How to make a tablet screen open on command?

Tags: android, tablet

i want to make my samsung galaxy tab 3 t111 screen to be permanent open only when it's connected to the microUSB. Trying to make a car navigation.

Comment: Flashing an custom rom in hope that it have this ability, and failed. I believe it's a way to script this in the original software or in a cyanogenmod rom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but it should work. If not, it'll get you in the right direction.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        //battery receiver setup
        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

        // Are we charging / charged?
        int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                     status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        if(isCharging) {
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Florin, could you test this and let us know if it works? Thanks.

Comment: I used autosleeper apk. Works fine

Comment: Could you answer your own question and mark it as correct then? This would help other users to find answers.